# How to multiply only the numeric values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

1. I read an Excel file using `pd.read_excel()`
2. One of the columns is called 'Energy Supply' containing strings and numbers
3. I use the following code:

`for x in energy['Energy Supply']:
     print(type(x))`

and the sample of results is:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'float'>
```

I need to multiply on the numeric values in this column by a million.

I tried the following code but it didn't work saying:

> unorderable types: str() > int()

```
for x in energy['Energy Supply']:
    if type(x) != 'str':
        while x>0:
            x = x*1000000
```

I tried:

```
energy['Energy Supply'].select_dtypes(include=['int64']) * 1000000
```

but it said:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'select_dtypes'

I tried:

```
energy['Energy Supply'] = [x * 1000000 for (type(x)=='int' 
                                            & x in energy['Energy Supply'])]
```

but got the syntax error.

Neither worked the following line:

```
energy.multiply(1000000, axis='Energy Supply', level=None, fill_value=None)
```

The following line doesn't give me errors but it doesn't do anything:

```
energy[energy.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns] *= 1000000
```

I really appreciate if someone you could please help me how to do this.

Comment: `if type(x) != 'str'` must be `if type(x) != str`...

Comment: haha coursera ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with mask created by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
energy = pd.DataFrame({'Energy Supply':[10, 1.0,'a']})
print(energy)
  Energy Supply
0            10
1             1
2             a

mask = pd.to_numeric(energy['Energy Supply'], errors='coerce').notnull()
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: Energy Supply, dtype: bool
```

Another solution is check `types`:

```
mask = energy['Energy Supply'].apply(lambda x: type(x) in [int, float])
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: Energy Supply, dtype: bool

energy['Energy Supply'] = energy['Energy Supply'].mask(mask, 
                                                       energy['Energy Supply'] * 1000000)
print (energy)
  Energy Supply
0      10000000
1         1e+06
2             a
```

Instead `mask` is possible use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select only numeric values:

```
print (energy.loc[mask, 'Energy Supply'])
0    10
1     1
Name: Energy Supply, dtype: object

energy.loc[mask, 'Energy Supply'] = energy.loc[mask, 'Energy Supply'] * 1000000
print (energy)
  Energy Supply
0      10000000
1         1e+06
2             a
```

Answer (score 2):

- `pd.to_numeric` with parameter `errors='coerce'`
- `dropna` + `update`

Using @jezrael's dataframe

```
energy = pd.DataFrame({'Energy Supply':[10, 1.0,'a']})

energy.update(pd.to_numeric(energy['Energy Supply'], 'coerce').mul(1e6).dropna())
energy

  Energy Supply
0         1e+07
1         1e+06
2             a
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
def multiply_if_number(x): # This could be a `lambda`
    return x * 1e6 if type(x) in [int,float] else x

energy['Energy Supply'] = energy['Energy Supply'].apply(multiply_if_number)
```